# multiple expand in ODATA binding

Tags: sapui5

How can I add multiple expands in ODATA binding? toCountry alone works but how also expand toRegion?

```
  oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: '/Region_Country',
    template: this.byId("CountriesTableTemplate"),
    filters: [
      new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: 'toRegion_ID',
        operator: "EQ",
        value1: sRegionId,
      })
    ],

    parameters: [
      { expand: 'toCountry' },
      { expand: 'toRegion' }
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Take a look at the sample snippet from the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158697/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OData binding with $expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516153/odata-binding-with-expand)

Try

```js
parameters:{
    expand: 'toCountry,toRegion'
}
```